# Symbian C++ Email Tool

Tags: symbian

I am new to this one. I want to develop the Email tool for s60 devices. How to start the email notification in symbian c++. I want to receive the email and send back to some other address.

Thanks in advance.. Please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there is more then one way how to do that. I guess you can start by looking one the *KCoreAppUIsNewEmailStatus* in the links below:
http://wiki.forum.nokia.com/index.php/KCoreAppUIsNewEmailStatus_API
and here:
http://wiki.forum.nokia.com/index.php/Category:E-Mail

If this will not be enough look on *CMsvXXX* classes and *CEmailAccounts* in SDK help. Short introduction to them is here:
http://wiki.forum.nokia.com/index.php/Messaging

BR
STeN

Comment: Thank u very much STeN. I will do this one.

Comment: I am glad to help you, if you will find any problems with Symbian C++ just ask here.. Good Luck

Comment: can I use the Symbian simulator for email processsing ? otherwise is it working only on the device.. THanks in advance.

Comment: Hi STeN, I am very new to this .. Could you please specify the step by step process for Send/ Receive email ? Here I am using the RSendAsMessage for mail sending.But The app is getting crashed.:( Please help me.. THanks in advance...

Comment: Hi, there is always reason for the app. crash, but I cannot tell you more without code snipped sending here. The application might 'Panic' so you will see the panic code or some method might 'leave', which is similar to throwing exception in pure C++... In both cases fixing the problem should be simple - just post here a code you are using. BR STeN

Comment: Hi, Thanks for response in short period.. I have enclosed the code as a new question. Kindly refer this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4020601/symbian-c-email-code-app-crash